# Problema com o Bundle

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e chegou a hora de trabalhar na performance do mesmo, e fui utilizar o esquema de `bundling` e `minification` do [MVC 4.5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification), ele funcionou como esperado, ele juntou todos os estilos que estão configurados num *bundle*, fez um *minified* e colocou num link só, para assim diminuir o número de *requests* da aplicação.

---

**Problema 1:**

Só que o problema é que estou utilizando o `Bootstrap 3` e o `Font Awesome`, e nestes caras há *caminhos relativos* para as fontes:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
    ...
}
```

---

**Problema 2:**

O primeiro problema é que ele não acha as fontes, e o segundo problema é que o `content:before` está sendo gerado com um caractere estranho:

```
.icon-reorder:before {
    content: "";
}
```

---

**Observação:** Acredito que este segundo problema pode ser por causa do primeiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri uma duas formas de solucionar este problema, a primeira é usando uma classe nativa do framework 4.5 `new CssRewriteUrlTransform();`, ficando o código desta forma:

```
IItemTransform cssFixer = new CssRewriteUrlTransform();

 #region Common Styles
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/commonStyle")
        .Include("~/Content/Vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css", cssFixer)
        .Include("~/Content/Vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reset.css", cssFixer)
        .Include("~/Content/Vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css", cssFixer)
 );
 #endregion
```

Neste trecho acima, eu criei apenas uma instância da classe e utilizei em vários arquivos, mas vi casos de pessoas fazendo um `new` para cada arquivo.

A outra solução um pouco mais elaborada, para não se criar varias instâncias ou ficar escrevendo `.Include` toda hora é utilizar [esta solução no github](https://github.com/bchristie/BundleBuilder.UrlResolver), ficando desta forma.

Método:

```
public static Bundle IncludeWithCssRewriteTransform(
this Bundle bundle, params String[] virtualPaths) {
    if (!(bundle is StyleBundle)) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Only available to StyleBundle", "bundle");
    }
    if (virtualPaths == null || virtualPaths.Length == 0) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("virtualPaths", "Cannot be null or empty");
    }
    IItemTransform itemTransform = new CssRewriteUrlTransform();
    foreach (String virtualPath in virtualPaths) {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(virtualPath)) {
            bundle.Include(virtualPath, itemTransform);
        }
    }
    return bundle;
}
```

Utilizando no seu Bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css/site").IncludeWithCssRewriteTransform(
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css",
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css",
    "~/Content/site.css"
));
```

Isto solucionou o meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu diretório `font` está na raiz, use assim:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
    ...
}
```

Comment: É infelizmente a estrutura do projeto não está desta forma, e não vai ser possível colocar esta pasta na raiz.

Answer (score 0):

Para usar os estilos tem uma dica que você deve seguir:
Coloque a sua pasta font junto com seus arquivos css, assim como a pasta images está na figura abaixo.

Na hora de registrar o seu css, coloque o caminho no bundle `"~/Content/themes/base/aqui_pode_irqualquernome"`, igual a sua estrutura de diretório

[image: estrutura de diretorios]